# Unable to reproduce app review crash swift_unknownRetain

Tags: ios, swift, crash

my app rejected due to crash occur when app review, but I can 
not reproduce the crash in my side.
symbol log:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001008cd74c     swift_unknownRetain (__hidden#20209_:380)
1   MYAPP                           0x00000001000d8830 specialized     HomeTableViewController.tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt : IndexPath)     -> () (HomeTableViewController.swift:0)
2   MYAPP                           0x00000001000d4754 @objc HomeTableViewController.tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt : IndexPath) -> () (HomeTableViewController.swift:0)
3   UIKit                           0x0000000193713078 0x1935d5000 + 1302648
4   UIKit                           0x00000001937c3b34 0x1935d5000 + 2026292
```

....
    not sure why UIKit not symboled?

crash occur when reviewer tap tableview row in homepage, the crash log not mentioned crash occur at which line, just at method tableView(*didSelecteRowAt*).

My dev env:
xcode8.1, swift3(no issues in xcode7.1), I just upgrade xcode to 8.1 and migrate code to swift3 style, 
my code for tableView(*didSelecteRowAt*)

```
let toViewControllerID = "\(self.toViewControllerList[section][row])"

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
 withIdentifier: toViewControllerID) as UIViewController

    if let nav = self.navigationController {

      nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

 }
```

the toViewControllerList is a 2D string array declare as homepage 
member variable,I make sure set correct ViewController storyboardID toViewControllerID.

what can cause swift_unknownRetain?
does anyone have same issues before? if you cannot reproduce app reviewer crash, how to do next? any suggestion? thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Alix, have you found it coz my app is rejected too with same reason.